# jQuery Fading effect occuring multiple times

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout, fadeto

I am trying to write a simple jQuery script to apply fading effect on footer. On mouseover event, it fades in with opacity = 1, and on mouse out event it fades out to opacity 0.01. I have applied this effect on parent div. The problem is, everytime I move mouse over child elements, it triggers the event and makes the div blink multiple times. How can I stop it? I want the mouseover and mouseout event to trigger when I hover over parent div and not when I move mouse inside the parent div.

Here is the [situation](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/w7Vbu/5/)

Thanks for any help in advance... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `stop()` function to prevent this: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(this).stop().fadeTo("fast",1.00);
$(this).stop().fadeTo("fast",0.01);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7Vbu/7/